# Create a dynamic component instead of duplicating Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to improve my React code, and I would like to know if instead of duplicating components with different variables, there was a possibility to create a single component and modify the variables?

```
 <Card>
       <CardTitle>Hey</CardTitle>
       <CardTexte>Text</CardTexte>
       <CardButton>Yo</CardButton>
     </Card>

     <Card>
       <CardTitle>Hey</CardTitle>
       <CardTexte>Text</CardTexte>
       <CardButton>Yo</CardButton>
     </Card>

    <Card>
    <CardTitle>Hey</CardTitle>
    <CardTexte>Text</CardTexte>
    <CardButton>Yo</CardButton>
    </Card>
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your components have the same sub-components and same style, you can use a wrapper to create a new component.

```
const WrapperComponent = ({ title, text, buttonText }) => {
  return (<Card>
    <CardTitle>{title}</CardTitle>
    <CardTexte>{text}</CardTexte>
    <CardButton>{buttonText}</CardButton>
    </Card>);
};
```

Comment: And how to call this component ?